# How to compare pointer address values?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

the code:

```
//is leaf?
if (root->left == root->right == NULL)
{
    cout << "\n is leaf";
    cout << ", l: " << root->left << ", r: " << root->right;
    return; //is leaf
}
```

returns:

```
is leaf, l: 004EDCD8, r: 004EDC70
```

this is not the expected behavior. They are clearly not equal AND not null, so why does this statement return true?

how do I compare pointer values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no three-way `==` operator. This is just as if you'd said:

```
if ((root->left == root->right) == NULL)
```

since `root->left != root->right`, that part would be false (`0`). Now we have:

```
if (0 == NULL)
```

which will evaluate to true.

What you want to say is:

```
if ((root->left == NULL) && (root->right == NULL))
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks, I assumed there was an "implicit" &&. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [operator precedence in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

The expression

```
(root->left == root->right == NULL)
```

is equivalent to

```
( (root->left == root->right) == NULL)
```

What you are looking for is:

```
(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//is leaf?
if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
{
    cout << "\n is leaf";
    cout << ", l: " << root->left << ", r: " << root->right;
    return; //is leaf
}
```

Comment: any specific reason for -1?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (root->left == root->right == NULL)
```

What is this statement intended to do?

I'm not 100% sure of the operator precedence here but you are doing a compare, which results in a Boolean result, and then comparing the Boolean result to something else.

Either way, this is a horrible statement to write. But clearly it's cause the wrong results here. You need to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)

should solve the problem.

Comment: No it won't. He's trying to compare the pointer values. And this question has already been answered correctly several times, and one of those answers has even been accepted.